# Running a separate process within a parent process

Tags: c, linux, exec, fork

I am creating a parent process that creates a child using fork(), and then creates a shared memory block that can be accessed by both the parent and the child. I have created child processes using the WIN32 api (by creating several .exe files and running them all and then calling them using the createProcess() function), but am a bit unsure of the steps for linux.

I have created a separate C file that contains the child's code. I assume I will create the child process using fork, then while in the child process (pid == 0)  use an exec() command to call the other C file? Do I need to first run the other file? Or can it just be sitting in the same directory?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: This is a fairly basic question. Have you tried to search for an answer or an example ("linux fork example")? I'm sure you'll find them abundant. But to answer your specific questions: No you don't call exec again after fork. fork already creates the new process. So in the (pid==0) case you just include whatever code you want the child to run. If it is in a different file then just call the function(s) that implement the child behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

After fork (), there are two processes, the parent and the child. The fork system call in the parent process returns the process id of the child. In the child process, fork () returns 0. So, if the return value of fork () is zero, you can call an exec system call with the executable file name of the program for the child process.